# Get date and month respecting local

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have a `Instant` and I would like to use a `DateTimeFormatter` to print a date with just date and month respecting the users `Local`.

For example: In the US I would like to print `MM/dd` (i.e. 05/31) whereas in Germany I would like to print `dd.MM` (i.e. 31.05).

How can I do this with java8 `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no pre-specified locale specific format String. `DD.MM` for a German locale isn't standard (even if it widely used, I have no idea). You will have to define which format you want to use for which Locale. Then it's just a matter of constructing the `DateTimeFormatter` with this format.

Comment: Please use "dd" instead of "DD" (latter one is day-of-year!).

Comment: @Tunaki So I have to create my own DateTimeFormatter for each Local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) method allows you to obtain a formatter that can output a date, but there is no data available in JDK 8 to output just a localized year-month. You would need to create a `Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter>` yourself. You may be able to use the data in CLDR to help.

Outputting an `Instant` is a separate issue, as an instant has no date or time part. The formatter will need to have a time-zone added using `withZone(ZoneId)` in order to output an `Instant` as a year-month.

Comment: thanks for answering. I also found this solution `Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter>`  and it works ... there are just to many locals :D